# jQuery Grep on JSON object using selected list item index

Tags: jquery, json, html-lists

I have an unordered list containining list items created from a JSON object. Each item in the JSON object has a property for index.

jQuery click event bound to UL:

```
$j("#courseGallery li").bind('click', function () {
   var index = $j("#courseGallery li").index(this);
   GetSelectedCourseInfo(index);
});
```

jQuery function to filter JSON data based on selected list item index in UL:

```
GetSelectedCourseInfo = function (index) {
    filteredData = $j.grep(sortedCourseData, function (e) {
        return e[index] === index;
    });
    if ($j("#altriaCourseDetails").children().length > 0) {
        $j(this).children().remove(); 
    }
    $j("#altriaCourseDetails").html($j("#selectedCourseTemplate").render(filteredData));
};
```

JSON data sample:

```
[
{
    "index":0,
    "title":"Foo1",
    "description":"Bar1",
},
{
    "index":1,
    "title":"Foo2",
    "description":"Bar2",
},
{
    "index":2,
    "title":"Foo3",
    "description":"Bar3",
}
]
```

Unfortunately, the item in the array is not being found based off the index. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run into problem like this put a break point in the place where you are having this issue. In this case it would be the first line of the

```
GetSelectedCourseInfo = function (index) {
filteredData = $j.grep(sortedCourseData, function (e) { //breakpoint here
    return e[index] === index;
});
```

that way you can examine the values of index and sortedCourseData. You can also do comparisons in the console of Development Tools once your break point is hit.

Answer (score 0):

you made a mistake inside your filter function
should be

```
return e.index === index
```

since you are accessing an object and not an array ;)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVWFt/

Comment: I neglected to mention that I previously had my code as such. The problem is that the index returned from the selected li does not match the index value from the JSON object. Therefore, even though the 4th li was selected (index being 3, the 4th value pair is selected from the JSON, however, it's value index is 8. It seems e.index reflects the item position from the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

ccI solved the problem using the title instead.

```
$j("#courseGallery li").bind('click', function () {
                var title = $j(this).children("#courseItemTitle").children("span").text();
                GetSelectedCourseInfo(title);
            });


GetSelectedCourseInfo = function (title) {
    filteredData = $j.grep(sortedCourseData, function (e) {
        return e.title === title;
    });
    if ($j("#altriaCourseDetails").children().length > 0) {
        $j(this).children().remove(); 
    }
    $j("#altriaCourseDetails").html($j("#selectedCourseTemplate").render(filteredData));
};
```